# How can I create objects for a ManyToMany fields in the same form in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, orm, model

So Django model forms make a multiple choice field out of a many to many field in the model. What I would like to do is to have a plus button similar to that of the admin site, that prompts you with a modal to create a **new** object for the many-to-many field, instead of just being able to select from the queryset of existing ones. Is mtm the right relation to use? Any pointers on how to achieve this?

[An example from the admin page where questions is a manytomany field in the Survey model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qrn4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short anwer, use ajax in your template. It will allow you to add a new object without refreshing your page.
If you search stack overflow there will be a lot of examples of how to implement ajax.